# Custom converter for primitive type

Tags: java, wicket, converters

In my wicket app, I want to use my own converter for some textfields with double (primitive type "double", not "Double" type) values.

I created mij converter and registered it, but only the method convertToString is called (when rendering), not the convertToObject (when submitting). It apparently comes from the fact that my textfield is mapped with a property of primitive type double (because if I change it to Double, then the method convertToObject is called).

Is this behaviour normal ? Is there a way to get my converter to work with a primitive type ? Or do I simply miss something in my understanding of how converters work ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you register your converter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem it is the way you are registering the converter, in order to register a converte of TYPE double

```
ConverterLocator converter= new ConverterLocator();
converter.set(Double.TYPE, DoubleConverter.INSTANCE);
```

see the source of ConverterLocator.class for more examples :)

Comment: Thanks a lot osdamv, I wan't aware of the trick, this works perfectly !